# Get Associated Data For LoopBack 4

Tags: loopback4

I have `User` & `Address` tables & models, for users I have ids `[23, 45, 54]` & I want to fetch Addresses for those users.

What will be best practice to fetch data?

I was trying somewhat like,

```
userRepository.find({
  where: [23, 45, 54],
  includes: [{relation: 'address'}]
})
```

Above will not work, I know as I am new to this `loopback 4` & did not work with exception.

Comment: Define "will not work" and quote the exception in fuill in your post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **where** filter incorrectly, the where filter should be an object.
For example if you want to find all the users with a property that equals one of the values 23, 45 or 54 then you should so something like this:

```js
userRepository.find({
  where: { propertyYouWantToMatch: { inq: [23, 45, 54] }
  ...
});
```

[Official 'inq' examples](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html#inq)

Resources to read:

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Querying-data.html
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Include-filter.html